# How to avoid VSCode in Ubuntu to create a file server-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.log

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know if this is an issue of the Ubuntu version or not, but every time I open VSCode, he creates a file like this:

[image]

How can I disable VSCode to create this file?

best regards
Paulo Aboim Pinto

Comment: have you tried with all extensions disabled, what is inside the log file

Comment: yes .. that was the problem .. I remove all the extensions and it's not generating the file anymore ..

Comment: you don't have to remove the extensions, just restart with all disabled, use the Extension bar top menu, enable them one by on and see which is the culprit